# return error message not showing - if else condition

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, authentication, conditional-statements

Sorry for asking silly question here. Problem is I didn't get the error message. I mean if email or password is incorrect I want to print this line :

`'{"status":"false","message":"Login incorrect. Try again"}';`

I've tried this code.

`else if($email != $dbemail || $password != $dbpassword) {   return '{"status":"false","message":"Login incorrect. Try again"}';  }`

But didn't get else message.

```
if ($checkDevice != 0 ) {

                     $email = $get['email'];
                     $password = $get['password'];

                            $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ? ");
                            $con->errorInfo();
                            $stmt->bindParam('1', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $stmt->bindParam('2', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $num_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
                            // print_r($get);

                            if($num_rows != 0 )
                            {
                                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                                {
                                    $dbemail = $row['email'];
                                    $dbpassword = $row['password'];
                                }
                                  if($email == $dbemail && $password == $dbpassword) 
                                  {
                                    return '{"status":"true","message":"Success. Login details correct."}';
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {   
                                    return '{"status":"false","message":"Login incorrect. Try again"}';
                                  }
                            }
                }
```

Comment: maybe try === instead of == ?

Comment: I've tried that too === but no success

Comment: have you tried to var_dump() all affected variables to see what is inside? The error must be elsewhere then.

Comment: I didn't tried that. But, if email and password is correct success message showing correctly...